# Experiencing Unexplained Errors with Push-to-Deploy for Python

Tags: python, git, google-app-engine, python-2.7, yaml

I'm attempting to use Push to Deploy with a Python project. It has worked previously, but today I recieved the error:

```
remote: Scanning pack: 100% (3/3), done.
remote: Storing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
remote: Processing commits: 100% (1/1), done.
remote: Starting execution...
remote: Created deployment: app.clouddev.gaeTemplate-d981b975f1ecaa6d.deployment_1389214392960
remote: Deployment 'app@clouddev@gaeTemplate-d981b975f1ecaa6d@deployment_1389214392960@1c3db1af-255d-43d4-945d-4ddbd98f34b2' is in PENDING.
remote: Dispatched
remote: Deployment failed, details: { Failed to load application, Couldn't find required field: version, none}
remote: Deployment 'app@clouddev@gaeTemplate-d981b975f1ecaa6d@deployment_1389214392960@1c3db1af-255d-43d4-945d-4ddbd98f34b2' failed.
remote: Deployment failed: Deployment failed, details: { Failed to load application, Couldn't find required field: version, none}
```

I attempted to correct the issue by remaking my app.yaml, to ensure all indentation was correct. The app runs correctly on the local dev server, and the app.yaml parses correctly.

```
application: app
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same issue on an app.yaml that hasnt changed in two months. I think Google's push to deploy is having issues. Grab some popcorn and watch netflix until it's fixed.

Comment: Sounds like a plan. Glad it's not just me, I couldn't find anyone else experiencing issues when I posted earlier :)